# How to adjust margin for small screens in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying different things to adjust the margin left for mobile (different)screen size. I am setting margin according to medium screen size using margin-left. And want to adjust for small screen size. Generally which method is useful and papular. Nothing is working in my case.What is wrong?

Can someone explain it with example. I am able to adjust screen size for column grid. But heading and header and footer is the issue. If I give heading and make it horizontal-align using margin left. How to change it for different size screen? What is wrong?

```
1)Do I need to add different style tags for each of them(mobile and medium size using media query. It is not working.) 


2)I trying to add class visible-xs and add mobile-margin (h1 view on mobile)

3)Add bootstrap utility class (h1 Utility class) 



<script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- font awsome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
<!-- font awsome -->
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
    
</script>

<style>
  .read{
        width:300px;
        height:70px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        background-color: darkgoldenrod;
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-top: 8px;
       margin-left: 400px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
.learn{
        width:300px;
        height:70px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        background-color: darkgoldenrod;
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-top: 8px;
      /* margin-left: 400px;*/
      /*  margin-top: 300px;*/
    }
    .mobile{
        width:400px;
        height:70px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        background-color: darkgoldenrod;
        padding-left: 100px;
    } 
.mobile-margin{
        margin-left: 50px;;
    }    

@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
margin-left: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
margin-left: 400px;
}
</style>




<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="read">Read more</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 ml-md-4 ml-sm-1">
            <h1 class="learn">Utility Class</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    
    
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mobile-margin visible-xs">
            <h1 class="mobile">view on mobile</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try Bootstrap classes to adjust according to the screen sizes. First set a default (mobile) and then change using `md` or `lg`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ml-0 ml-lg-5">Margin Test</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ml-0 ml-lg-3">Margin Test</div>
</div>
```

margin-left is set to `0` for mobile screens and margin-left is set to `5` for large screens

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example of a heading H1 element.

First make sure to add bootstrap css link correctly to your page.

In bootstrap you can use the `m` class for margin and the `p` class for padding. In addition you can optionally set the side on which you want to apply margin or padding. Use `ml` for example to set margin left. You can give it a value between 0 and 5. For example, `ml-3`. You can also specify multiple values for multiple screen sizes as shown in the below example:

```
<h1 class="ml-5 ml-md-3 ml-lg-0">Header Text</h1>
```

In this example, the heading element will have a margin of 5, it will change to 3 when screen size reaches medium and it will change to 0 when screen size reaches large.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is give the class name in the media screens.You haven't given your class name and just given margin-left

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
margin-left: 400px;
}
```

You can specify the name like this

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
        .read {
          margin-left: 50px;
        }
      }

      @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .read {
          margin-left: 400px;
        }
      }
```

You can center the heading through

```
<h4 class="text-center">
<h4 class="text-lg-center">h4: centered in large screen and centered in med/smaller</h4>
<h4 class="text-md-center">h4: centered in medium/large screen and centered in smaller</h4>
<h4 class="text-sm-center">h4: centered in small/medium/large except extra small</h4>
```

and for buttons centering

```
<div class="col text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Centered button</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: What I am trying do is, setting heading / button in the center. But  looks like ml-4 or ml-5    doesn't work. Using media query I am able to achieve it.  But using bootstrap classes, not working.ml - 4 is not enough to move heading in center. (for all screen types heading should be in center ) How many column and what size div should I create ?I created  < div class="col-md-12"> as I want full screen size and heading in the center. Want to make div responsive.

Comment: See the answer.In bootstrap you can use text-lg-center to display heading in center on large screens.and col text-center to center a button